# Recommended Space Simulator?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, alternate-worlds

Call this the equivalent of the map simulator, only for space.  Does such an animal even exist?  Finding downloadable map resources is easy.  This, not so much.

I'm essentially looking for a realistic builder/simulator for planetary systems like our own, not software that simply models our own.  It needs to have a build/sandbox capability.

Comment: There are a number of options available, from the very basic dan-ball planet sandbox simulator, to universe sandbox on steam.(those are the only two I can remember the names of.) for a really convoluted option you could even use an application like Geometer's sketchpad, although it would be a lot of work. Depending on what other criteria are a lot of possible answers. Does it need to be 3d or 2d? does it need to be free?(if not what is your upper limit on price?) what kind of computer will you be running it on? How detailed does it need to be?

Comment: I agree with @Jonathon. There are a lot of unanswered questions you've left open-ended. You need to narrow down the question. Welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: You might look at [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/24004/2113) to see if any of those answers help you.  Or you may want to differentiate this question from that question more.

Comment: If it can't be solved with Kerbal Space Program, it shouldn't be solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What software can prototype a planetary system?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/what-software-can-prototype-a-planetary-system).

Answer (score 1):

There's a game [Universe Sandbox](http://universesandbox.com/) that may be what you're looking for.